# React: SVG dynamically add CSS by id or class

Tags: reactjs, svg

In React I have a svg file such as `mySVG.svg`

```
<svg width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 50 50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect id="Unit1" class="class1" x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" fill="blue"/>
  <rect id="Unit2" class="class1" x="10" y="10" width="10" height="10" fill="blue"/>
  <rect id="Unit3" class="class2" x="20" y="20" width="10" height="10" fill="blue"/>
</svg>
```

Then, in the component file `Example.tsx`, I would like to dynamically set the svg's colors based on passed in props

```
import  { ReactComponent as mySvg} from 'assets/mySVG.svg';

export function Example(props:{highlighted:string}):ReactElement {

  if (props.highlighted === 'Unit1') {  
    return (
      <mySvg
        //set unit 1 fill color to red
      />
    );
  }

  return (
    <mySvg />
  );
}
```

How would I accomplish dynamically setting the fill color of the svg based on id and className of the svg paths?

Importing a static css file with the colors defined won't work because I need this to work dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the svg file `mySVG.svg`

```
<svg width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 50 50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect id="Unit1" class="class1" x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" fill="blue"/>
  <rect id="Unit2" class="class1" x="10" y="10" width="10" height="10" fill="blue"/>
  <rect id="Unit3" class="class2" x="20" y="20" width="10" height="10" fill="blue"/>
</svg>
```

I created a helper function to get the DOM of a given Ref `getDOMNodeById.ts`

```
export type DOMNode = Element | ChildNode | Text | null;

export function getDOMNodeById(componentDOMNode:DOMNode, id:string): DOMNode | void {
  if (componentDOMNode?.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
    const element = componentDOMNode as Element;

    if (element.id === id) {
      return element;
    }
    else if (element.hasChildNodes()) {
      for (let i=0; i<element.childNodes.length; i++) {
        const childNode = element.childNodes[i];
        const result = getDOMNodeById(childNode, id);
        if (result) {
          return result;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

export const isHTMLElement = (v:any): v is HTMLElement => {
    return v instanceof Element || v instanceof HTMLElement;
}
```

Tying it all together, add a Ref to the svg react component, call the helper function to grab the DOM of Ref, then mutate the returned Element `Example.tsx`

```
import  { ReactComponent as mySvg} from 'assets/mySVG.svg';
import { DOMNode, getDOMNodeById, isHTMLElement } from './getDOMNodeById';

export function Example(props:{highlighted:string}):ReactElement {
  const svgRef = useRef(null);
  const svgDOM = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(svgRef.current);

  if (props.highlighted === 'Unit1') {  
    const unit = getDOMNodeById(svgDOM, 'Unit1');
    if (isHTMLElement(unit)) {
      unit.style.fill = 'red';
    }
  }

  return (
    <mySvg ref={svgRef} />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can manipulate the file you are importing, but I think the easiest way to do this is to embed your SVG inside a JSX component or convert it to one.

See an example here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-galois-1tfce

EDIT: Added node manipulation and reserialization to the SVG content.

Comment: The svg file is subject to frequent changes, so I'd like to be able to do this without the need to directly edit the svg file, and keep it self-contained in a .svg file. Is there a way to directly access the path by Id, like how getElementById works in regular JavaScript?

Comment: @KyleMcCaf alternatively, you can put the `mySvg` in `<div className="my-svg-style" />` and add the `.my-svg-style svg` and `.my-svg-style svg rect` styles

Comment: I updated the codesandbox, please take a look. basically if your loader is set to import the svg as plain text you can parse get the selector change the value parse it back and insert to the component. Very naive and potentially unsafe but it works and maybe this is what you want to achieve.

Comment: I see how the svg is being dynamically assigned fill colors via props, which is very cool. However, it doesn't quite help me out as the fill color isn't being assigned based on id or class. I need a way to update the color without editing the original svg file.

Comment: I thin your question then is confusing you can just apply styles to your svg like any xml/html node. #Unit2 {fill: green}; . please check the example again (look in the file App.js). This can be achieved in many ways. if you have style loader you can do ```import './stylesheet.css';``` and the styles will be injected to the document.

Answer (score 2):

firstly, I would like to recommend [this site](https://react-svgr.com/playground/) to you, it converts ordinary svg code into a jsx component.
It is enough for you to transfer the necessary props to the component with your svg
`mySVG.jsx` :

```
import * as React from "react"

function mySVG({color = "#000000", className = "", width = 50, height = 50}) {
  return (
    <svg 
      className={className} 
      width={width} 
      height={height} 
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      <path fill={color} d="M0 0h10v10H0zM10 10h10v10H10z" />
      <path fill={color} d="M20 20h10v10H20z" />
    </svg>
  )
}

export default mySVG
```

and transfer the necessary data to your component with svg

```
import mySVG from "/you/path/mySVG"


// other code.... 


  return (
    <mySVG 
       color="#ffffff" 
       height={100} 
       width={100} 
       className="my-svg-style" 
    />
  );
```

Comment: The svg file is subject to frequent changes, so I need a way to manipulate it via id/class without manipulating the original svg file